# Issues with minSdkVersion

Tags: android, manifest, surfaceview

I found an Android project with the following line in its AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"/>
```

if I change from “3” to any other number, some animation elements presented in a SurfaceView don’t behave correctly; I would like to use android:minSdkVersion=“8”; any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's like trying to make things work in stone age. One way would be to look into the support libraries and their behavior changes.

Comment: Wow minSDK = 3 is a bit old. You can follow these Twitter accounts: https://twitter.com/minsdkversion - https://twitter.com/targtSdkVersion - and the humoristic https://twitter.com/maxSdkVersion.

Comment: Thanks Murat; could you please specify a bit? I'm not sure how to check behavior changes in support libraries.